# ReactJS gives me an error every time when I try to use govuk-frontend components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

[This is the error that I received all the time when I put govuk-frontend components.
I’m using Visual Studio 2022 with ReactJS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74aRv.jpg)

I need to create a page that will show medical records of the registered patients, I need to use ReactJS with Visual Studio 2022 and GOV-UK Design System. So I thought to try to put header just to see will it works and when I try to run the code it gives me an TypeError and something about useDebugValue.
Any ideas how to fix this annoying error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.